# CPU is busy after installation of Geforce graphic driver 340.52 (NvNetworkService.exe= 12 % of cpu)

Tags: drivers, cpu, graphics

CPU is busy after installation of nvidia Geforce graphic driver 340.52 (NvNetworkService.exe= 12 % of cpu)
Any body knows why?
I have Dell XPS L502x laptop.
This problem occurred just after installation of Geforce graphic driver 340.52. My laptop fan is always on it's high speed and is active permanently. 
After tracing the source of the heat I found NvNetworkService.exe with almost 12 to 13 percent of cpu activity. 
The weird part is most of the activity is on one core and it cause sometimes my system shut down unreasonably.
For now I decided to change Geforce driver to the older version.
The only reason I came to this driver was BlueStack which always alerts me about oldness of my graphic card driver, but it runs with older versions too.
Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: This isn't a programming question.

Comment: Any professional in this field, need help. Thanks

Comment: "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User."

Comment: disable the service in the services MMC snapin (**services.msc**)

Answer (score -1):

NVIDIA diabled GPU based PhysX if a non-NVIDIA second GPU is detected in your system. This change was introduced in 340.52. This puts more load on the CPU since all PhysX calculations are performed by the CPU and that is why your CPU usage and temps will rise accordingly.

[Check this link for more information.](http://wccftech.com/nvidia-disables-physx-support-vendor-mixed-setup-340-52/)